# Plugin and dialog together

Tags: plugins, dynamics-crm-2011

If I use a dialog to create an instance of an entity, will it fire the plugin registered to that message (i.e. *Create* on *EntityA*)?

If not, how can I link that plugin to that message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're safe to use the plugin. It will catch the dispatched message as long as you've registered it correctly.

The plugin will, in fact, react to the following events.

- Creation of an instance (a record) by the user from the GUI.
- Creation of an instance by a workflow.
- Creation of an instance by a dialog.
- Creation of an instance by a code from an extern program.
- Creation of an instance by... *anything*.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, the plugin will always fire regardless of the source of the message.